# Nginx v1.14.2 -- too many redirects

Tags: web, nginx

In my limited experience with Nginx, I get too many redirects when I deploy many WEB projects on the one domain.

I want to use one 'location' to match multiple items.

File path: `/mnt/vue/web` and `/mnt/vue/admin` and `/mnt/page/web`

When I visit `https://${domain}/page/single`, it is wrong. It redirects to `https://${domain}/page/single/index.html/index.html/index.html/...`

When I visit `https://${domain}/vue/web`, it is ok.

I've tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Here is my Nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen       443 http2;
    server_name  ${domain};

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate   /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/web/web.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/web/web.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;
    ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE:ECDH:AES:HIGH:!NULL:!aNULL:!MD5:!ADH:!RC4;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # wechat verify
    root /mnt/wechat;

    # for vue h5-wechat
    location ~ /(.*)/web {
        root /mnt;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/web/index.html =404;
    }

    # for vue admin-web
    location ~ /(.*)/admin {
        root /mnt;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /$1/admin/index.html =404;
    }

    # for api
    location ~ /(.*)/api/(.*)$ {
        proxy_pass http://172.16.184.254:$1;
        rewrite /(.*)/api/(.*)$ /$2 break;
    }

    # for single pages  !!!!!  Where the problem occurred.
    location ~ /(.*)/single/ {
        alias /mnt/$1/web/;
        index index.html;
    }

    # for cache
    location ~ /(css|img|js|fonts|image)/ {
        add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=300";
    }

    location /files {
        rewrite /files/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass https://172.16.92.152;
    }

}
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name ${domain};
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
   #rewrite ^(.*)$  https://$host$1 permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `alias` within a *regular expression* `location` block, you need to capture the entire URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/(.*)/single/(.*)$ {
    alias /mnt/$1/web/$2;
    index index.html;
}
```